# Sum of daily data from minutes data in R(different number of data per day)?

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, time-series

all, my data looks something like this:

01/04/2006,900,11756

01/04/2006,901,7492

01/04/2006,902,4012

01/04/2006,903,3190
....

The first column are Dates while the second column are time as 9:00. 
I want to **get the daily sum of the third column.**

**Note that the date may not be continuous, and time may not be continuous.**

To find all the dates in the data, I can use **unique( ) function**.

Comment: Try `aggregate(value~Date, df, sum)` where `value` is the 3rd column, Date is the first column in your dataset "df"

Comment: @akrun, Your answer seems to work, but the returned results are in a strange order, what kind of order of data is aggregate() returning ?

Comment: You want the daily sum so this implies that we only need to take care of the date column. I wondered if something should be done with the time column or if it can be ignored?

Comment: @akrun, thanks for what you pointed out. Would you mind to post your comments as answer? I will tick it. ^_^

Comment: @GeekCat It is already a duplicate :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following uses the plyr package and gives the daily sum of the third column

```
library(plyr)

dd <- as.Date(c("01/04/2006", "01/04/2006", "01/04/2006", "01/04/2006"), format="%d/%m/%Y")
time <- as.character(c("9:00","9:01","9:02","9:03"))
val <- as.numeric(c(11756,7492,4012,3190))

dat <- data.frame(dd,time,val)

ddply(dat, .(dd), summarize, val = sum(val))
```